# How to connect to RFT(client side) through RQM(server side)?

Tags: rft, ibm-rational

I am new to RFT and RQM.
I am able to connect and run RFT scripts through RQM with the help of RFT adapter on client machine,

I wanted to know if there is any way i could connect to RFT(client side) through RQM(server side)?
Using may be some kind of RQM adapter or something like that.

Also, is it possible for RQM to fetch RFT scripts(automatically) from any physical or virtual machine it is running on?

Answer (score 0):

RFT adapter registers itself to the RQM server.  I din't quite get what you mean by

> if there is any way i could connect to RFT(client side) through RQM(server side)?

You can configure your testscripts to be local to a machine or you can keep them on a shared location  and then register that location as a shared location in RQM.

In case of scripts that are local to the machine where the adapter is running the scripts are already on the machine so  there is no need of fetching as such.

In case of shared location execution , the scripts first get downloaded to the machine where the adapter is running(to a temp folder)  and then they execute locally.

In both the cases the results are uploaded back to the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prakash ! That helped!